# Windows command: Set exit code of chained commands based on first command

Tags: azure, cmd, azure-batch

i have this case scenario (this is command that is executed on Azure Batch task):

```
cmd /c MainApp.exe & Util.exe
```

What i need is to exit this whole command with exit code from MainApp.exe as Util.exe exits always with 0 code.

I have tried something like this with different brackets positions and nothing have worked as needed.

```
cmd /c (MainApp.exe) & set taskExitCode=%ERRORLEVEL% & Util.exe & exit %taskExitCode%
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `Util.exe` is actually not called in the context of the `cmd` instance you initiate, but I guess you want that; to resolve this, either escape the ampersand or quote the command line:

   ```cmd
   cmd /C MainApp.exe ^& Util.exe
   ```

   or:

   ```cmd
   cmd /C "MainApp.exe & Util.exe"
   ```
2. Since you are trying to write *and* read a variable in the same command line/block, you need to enable and apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which can be achieved by `cmd /V`, like this:

   ```cmd
   cmd /V /C MainApp.exe ^& set /A ERR=!ErrorLevel! ^& Util.exe ^& exit !ERR!
   ```

   or:

   ```cmd
   cmd /V /C "MainApp.exe & set /A ERR=!ErrorLevel! & Util.exe & exit !ERR!"
   ```

   This works only given that `MainApp.exe` also sets the `ErrorLevel`, which is not always the same as the exit code. If it does not, you could try this (the `||` operator forces `ErrorLevel` to equal the current exit code):

   ```cmd
   cmd /V /C MainApp.exe ^|^| rem/ ^& set /A ERR=!ErrorLevel! ^& Util.exe ^& exit !ERR!
   ```

   or:

   ```cmd
   cmd /V /C "MainApp.exe || rem/ & set /A ERR=!ErrorLevel! & Util.exe & exit !ERR!"
   ```

---

In case `Util.exe` does not need to be executed in case `MainApp.exe` returns a non-zero exit code, do this (so the exit code of `MainApp.exe` survives):

```cmd
cmd /C MainApp.exe ^&^& Util.exe
```

or:

```cmd
cmd /C "MainApp.exe && Util.exe"
```

If `MainApp.exe` really does not set `ErrorLevel`, you could try the following:

```cmd
cmd /C MainApp.exe ^&^& Util.exe || rem/
```

or:

```cmd
cmd /C "MainApp.exe && Util.exe || rem/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. Command `cmd /V /C MainApp.exe ^& set /A ERR=!ErrorLevel! ^& Util.exe ^& exit !ERR!` worked like a charm.